# NVIDIA SLI - Screen blinking

Tags: windows, nvidia-graphics-card, sli

I have tried multiple drivers and multiple games ( Games tried, Darkfall and source based games).
Drivers tried ( 18x,29x and 24x).

When i disable SLI the games work perfectly.

A description of the blinking effect would be its like one of the video cards are not sending the image to screen.

This is a laptop if it mathers, im hoping i can fix this issue without having to send in the laptop for repair.

Answer (score 0):

My roommate had a similar problem with his alienware laptop - one card would stop sending frames to the other.

He found a working driver at [Laptop Video 2 Go](http://www.laptopvideo2go.com), but had to try several until he found a good one that worked. (The site hosts tweaked driver packages for specific setups found in laptops, if I remember correctly.